# How to detect when a blackberry application is in active state?

Tags: java, blackberry

iphone has a method called applicationDidBecomeActive, was wondering if there was something similar in blackberry SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe Application.activate():

> The system invokes this method when it
>   brings this application to the
>   foreground. By default, this method
>   does nothing. Override this method to
>   perform additional processing when
>   being brought to the foreground.